# Как если обработчик получил нужное значение, сделать другой обработчик?

Tags: post, php, обработка

```
<form method='post' action=' '>
<?if(isset($_POST['redgr'])or die(mysql_error()))
        {   
    $g1=$_POST['group'];    
    $g2=$_POST["дисциплина"];
    $g3=$_POST['vlec'];
    $g4=$_POST['vlab'];
    $g5=$_POST['vpract'];
    $g6=$_POST['plec'];
    $g7=$_POST['plab'];
    $g8=$_POST['ppract'];
    $g9=$_POST['phomework'];
    $g10=$_POST['pcontrol'];
    $g11=$_POST['plet'];
    $g12=$_POST['prem'];
    $g13=$_POST['premkurs'];
    $g14=$_POST['examcr'];
    $g15=$_POST['pkurs'];

                $adstudent=("INSERT INTO `ведомость` (`группа`, `дисциплина`,`посещение лекций`, 
                `посещение лабораторных`,`посещение практик`, `баллы за лекцию`
                , `баллы за лабу`,`баллы за практику`, `баллы за дз`, `баллы за контрольную`, 
                `баллы за летучки`, `премия лектора`, `премия курсовой работы`
                , `экзамен или зачет`, `курсовая работа`) 
                VALUES ('$g1','$g2','$g3','$g4','$g5','$g6','$g7','$g8','$g9','$g10','$g11','$g12','$g13','$g14','$g15')");
                $studentsql=mysql_query($adstudent)or die(mysql_error());  
        if($studentsql)
        {
        echo 'Ведомость с выбранными работыми успешно составленна.<br>назначьте остальные параметры';
        }
        }
    if(isset($_POST['redgr'])or die(mysql_error()))
        {   
    $g1=$_POST['group'];    
    $g2=$_POST["дисциплина"];
    $g3=$_POST['vlec'];
    if($g3=='on')
        {
                echo "Сколько ?<input type='text' name='collec' >
                <input type='submit' name='adcollec'>";}

                if(isset($_POST['adcollec']))
                    {   
                        $acol=$_POST['collec'];
                        echo count($acol). "ONO<br>";   
            }
}
    exit();
?>
</form>
```

никак не реагирует на посыл

```
if(isset($_POST['adcollec']))
                    {   
                        $acol=$_POST['collec'];
                        echo count($acol). "ONO<br>";   
            }
```

Comment: Давно не видел такого образцового быдлокода.

Comment: тут помощи вообще то просят

Comment: Кто-то просит, а кто-то комментирует.

Comment: Ну как тут не вспомнить [лурка!](http://lurkmore.to/PHP)

Comment: угар...ну помогите!=)

Comment: А если вы у вас было не 15, а 1200 POST-переменных, то как бы вы написали, мне интересно?

Comment: Во-первых, я же уже говорил что надо [сделать](http://hashcode.ru/questions/224675/php-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-if-isset-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2-if-%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B2-if-isset).

Во-вторых, если задачу нельзя формулизировать, значит она поставлена не верно. Я смотрю - вы плохо понимаете, что должен выполнять ваш код. Начните сначала. Каждое действие которое должно быть выполнено - это отдельная функция. Может быть в таком виде вам будет проще не допускать ошибок.

Comment: заполняется ведомость  с различными типами занятий (где то они вкл где то выкл) и необходимо добавить кол-во занятий если тип уроков в связке группа-дисциплина включен. ну не как ни выполняется  последний кусок

Comment: Я вам еще раз повторю - если необходимо вывести информацию - сделайте вывод в отдельной функции. Которая только и делает, что выводит. Ничего больше.

Необходимо добавить запись в БД - добавляйте в отдельной функции. Не смешивайте все в одном месте как в мясорубке.

Почему вывод 'echo "Сколько ?..."' зависит от PHP? Это чисто клиентская задача. Навесьте JS на кнопку выбора. Выбрали - показали сообщение с инпутом, не выбрали - скрыли.

Т.е., если грубо, ваш код должен быть примерно таким:

    if (receiveValues()) {
        updateJournal();
    }
    addResultToForm();
    printForm();

Comment: Инъекции, посоны!!!111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
or die(mysql_error())
```

Конструкция используется только в связке:
    mysql_query("select * from table where column='$value'") or die(mysql_error()));

такое понятие как $_POST["дисциплина"];
очень извращенное. Ключи должны быть только латинские или это у вас такой интересный подход? тогда нужно его кодировать в язык который понимает php что бы сделать то что вы хотите и то не уверен что получиться.

По красоте оформления - думаю вам лучше отделить html от обработчиков и держать их в одном месте.

P.S. [[@Zhukov Roman](/users/10590/zhukov-roman)](/users/10590/zhukov-roman)
Поддерживаю и одновременно не поддерживаю.
Образцового быдлокода я и правда не видел. Но человек учиться - и согласитесь вы точно так же начинали... Опускать людей просто не этично на сколько бы сильно вы их не превосходили в познаниях той или иной области..